# Django Filter Base Class by Child Class Names

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model inheritance structure in Django:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # stuff

class A(Parent):
    # stuff

class B(Parent):
    # stuff

class C(Parent):
    # stuff

and the list goes on.
```

I am using InheritanceManager of django-model-utils to filter objects like:

```
Parent.objects.filter(foo=bar).select_subclasses()
```

This works well when I want to filter all subclasses. What I want to do is to filter A and B objects, but not C objects. I want to do this with a single query like

```
Parent.objects.filter(foo=bar, __class__.__name__=A, __class__.__name__=B).select_subclasses()
```

Is it possible to do such a filtering operation, and if possible how?

Comment: why not just do `A.objects.filter(foo=bar)` etc?

Comment: I want to filter all objects with a single query, instead of multiple queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly is possible to do this in a single query!

It all comes from the way Django builds up fields to refer to the relationships between the parent and child models. Each child has a `parent-ref` of some sort, which has a `related_name`. You can query on these.

You'll probably find it easiest to start up a `./manage.py shell`, and import your parent model class, and then perform a nonsense query:

```
Parent.objects.filter(foo='bar')
```

This should show you the available fields for querying: you can then work out how to build the query:

```
Parent.objects.filter(is_active=True).filter(
    models.Q(a__isnull=False) |
    models.Q(b__isnull=False)
).select_subclasses()
```

This will perform a single query that will fetch all objects of A, all objects of B, that have `is_active` set to `True`, and downcast them.

The thing it is worth pointing out is that `.select_subclasses()` is unable to detect which models are going to be included, so it joins in *all* subclasses.

However... you can pass values to `select_subclasses` so it only joins (and downcasts) to those subclasses:

```
Parent.objects.filter(is_active=True).filter(
    models.Q(a__isnull=False) |
    models.Q(b__isnull=False)
).select_subclasses('a', 'b')
```

Now, we are no longer joining to tables "c" through "z"!

Comment: Wow its ben a while since I asked this question :) Your answer directly solves the problem mentioned in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its usually not considered the best to setup inheritable like that because then each SQL query will have to do a join. That can make your performance much slower. To increase performance, you can use `abstract` Meta value:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # stuff
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This way each table is independent and hence performance will be faster.

If that is no applicable to you, I don't think its possible to do something like that in a single query because the fields within the table/model do not contain any information in what table are they located. In that case you will most likely have to somehow subclass the `InheritanceManager` however I'm not sure what to do there. If you do, using content_types then might be of some help.

If that is too much work, then you can always do a simple hack (more of a monkey patching...). I know its not pretty but it will work:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # stuff
    table = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='parent')

class A(Parent):
    # stuff
    table = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='a')

class B(Parent):
    # stuff
    table = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='b')


# and then something like
# please note that I've never used django-model-utils
# so don't know the correct syntax
Parent.objects.filter(foo=bar, table__in=['parent', 'a']).select_subclasses()
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I did not use an abstract base class because I wanted the ability to filter base class objects using a single query instead of using a seperate query for each subclass. I just wanted to filter a subset of base classes at some places, and another subset an another place. I'll post here if I find a satisfactory solution

Comment: Abstract inheritance and Multi-table inheritance have distinctly different properties. Using MTI is appropriate when you want to be able to perform a single query to fetch a range of distinct types, as the OP suggests. Sure, there can be a penalty to join the tables, but databases are pretty good at handling that (and it's always going to beat seperate queries).

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky solution that's worked for me, without adding more information to the database:

```
letters = Parent.objects.filter(foo=bar)
for letter in letters:
    if type(letter) == C:
        letters.exclude(id=c.id)
```

Or, alternatively, if you add information to the models without adding fields:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # stuff

class A(Parent):
    code = 'A'
    # stuff

class B(Parent):
    code = 'B'
    # stuff

class C(Parent):
    code = 'C'
    # stuff
```

And then...

```
letters = Parent.objects.filter(foo=bar)
for letter in letters:
    if letter.child().code == 'C':
        letters.exclude(id=c.id)
```

Works for my purposes, though still a hack...